# How to make scrollview last index like tableview last row

Tags: ios, scrollview, tableview

I am using page controller to display one by one page by scrolling horizontally.But my requirement is to display,when it comes to last page it should be elastic in nature as if when table view reaches at last row.

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];

Comment: it should be looked as if we are using pull to refresh at last page

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually set the elastic nature of the last page of the pageviewcontroller.
The datasource object of your pageviewcontroller returns the before and after viewcontroller that will be displayed on the pageviewcontroller when it is swiped either right or left respectively.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
}
```

Using above two methods you can decide which viewcontroller should be displayed before or after the current viewcontroller.
When you return nil in the above methods ,the pageviewcontroller will come to know that there are no more viewcontrollers to display next and will by default give you that bouncy effect.

You can refer to this tutorial from AppCoda for further understanding [UIPageViewController Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

Comment: yes,i know that,but my requirement to do so alike behaviour of table view last row footer

Comment: i am also not using any controller,simply on a scroller view i am adding a view of 768*600 in a page array.

Comment: Check in the attributes inspector of the scrollview.
You will find Bounces attribute which can be turned on or off which by accident might be unchecked.
Hope that solves the problem.